# SilverStripe 3.1+ Dynamically creating page redirects

Tags: php, redirect, url-rewriting, silverstripe

I have a page type 'ProductPage', it has tabs that are navigated to like so:

/ProductPageUrlSegment/?tab=video

/ProductPageUrlSegment/?tab=audio

/ProductPageUrlSegment/?tab=photos

I'd like for redirects to be created when each new product page is created so that if you navigated **/ProductPageUrlSegment/video** it goes to **/ProductPageUrlSegment/?tab=video**

and the same for all tabs. I'm not clear if I should be using Routing https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/controllers/routing/ or redirection https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/controllers/redirection/

I have a link function for another project which goes to the parent page

```
public function Link() {
    return $this->Parent()->Link() . '#' . $this->URLSegment;
}
```

Mine would be something like:

```
public function LinkVideo() {
    return $this->Link()->'/?=video' . '#' . $this->URLSegment->'/video';
}
```

I don't have the knowledge to work this out so any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will achieve the above, by handling the URL as an action and then redirecting to the same page, but with the get variable set...

```
class ProductPage extends Page {

}

class ProductPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'video',
        'audio',
        'photos',
    );

    public function video() {
         $this->redirect($this->Link().'?tab=video');
    }
    public function audio() {
        $this->redirect($this->Link().'?tab=audio');
    }
    public function photos() {
        $this->redirect($this->Link().'?tab=photos');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I'm getting this error: "too many redirects occurred trying to open page" The page is also instantly trying to go to "/?tab=video" it needs to just go to the product URL and after that the tabs can be navigated and only redirect when /videos etc is entered.

Comment: Your answer works for other pages, but not for my product page so I must have something stopping it working... I accepted your answer as it does work.

Comment: Turns out one of the actions in my case 'video' matches one of my $has_many relationships and GridFields and seems to conflict, renaming the action made it all work, or I guess I could change the relationship.