# SilverStripe 3.1+ Using PHP to dynamically change the URL slug of a Redirector

Tags: php, redirect, silverstripe

This is an extension of my original question [SilverStripe 3.1+ Dynamically creating page redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947205/silverstripe-3-1-dynamically-creating-page-redirects)

I have a product page URL
a) www.mysite.com/category/subcat/productid
You can visit this page via a a separate redirector page
b) www.mysite.com/productid

Page 'a' has tabs which can be visited via
c) www.mysite.com/category/subcat/productid/tabid

I would like to use PHP to dynamically create links / redirectors for each product page create so it can be visited by:

1) A short URL using only its 'predicted' shown in 'b' (I can do this by creating a page redirector but this is long winded for a large number of products.
2) Create a short URL for each tab link as well, so 'c' would be redirected from: d) www.mysite.com/productid/tabid

The 'tabid' can be hard coded and in my case would be: audio, videos, pictures, firmware

Currently using the code in my ProductPage.php

```
class ProductPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {


private static $allowed_actions = array(

    'audio',
    'pictures',
    'firmware',
    'videos',
);


public function audio() {
    $this->redirect($this->Link().'?tab=audio');
}
public function pictures() {
    $this->redirect($this->Link().'?tab=pictures');
}
public function firmware() {
    $this->redirect($this->Link().'?tab=firmware');
}
public function videos() {
     $this->redirect($this->Link().'?tab=videos');
}
```

Allows me to go from /video to /?tab=video but this of course does not shorten the URL which is the final result I'm after.
Possibly this could be done in an extension of the RedirectorPage.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `onBeforeHTTPError404` to hook into when a 404 error is called and to redirect any product found.

We create a `ProductRedirectExtension` with an `onBeforeHTTPError404` function. This function will get called when a page cannot be found, but before the system returns a 404 error. The code in here will check if a `ProductPage` exists with a `URLSegment` with the first part of user's URL string. If a `ProductPage` is found we then check if the second part of the user's URL string is one of the tab keywords. After that the user is redirected to the page.

**ProductRedirectExtension.php**

```
class ProductRedirectExtension extends Extension {

    public function onBeforeHTTPError404( $request ) {
        $urlSegment = $request->param('URLSegment');
        $action = strtolower($request->param('Action'));
        $page = ProductPage::get()->filter('URLSegment', $urlSegment)->first();

        if ($page) {
            $link = $page->Link();

            if ($action == 'audio' || $action == 'pictures' || $action == 'firmware' || $action == 'videos') {
                $link .= '?tab=' . $action;
            }

            $response = new SS_HTTPResponse();
            $response->redirect($link, 301);

            throw new SS_HTTPResponse_Exception($response);
        }
    }
}
```

We enable this extension with the following config settings.

**config.yml**

```
RequestHandler:
  extensions:
    - ProductRedirectExtension

ContentController:
  extensions:
    - ProductRedirectExtension

ModelAsController:
  extensions:
    - ProductRedirectExtension
```

Comment: Worked really well, some of the tabs are not always active on the page and it just goes to the page anyway which is ideal, and still works with only the product url segment without the additional keyword. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The shortest you could go is `www.mysite.com/product/productid/tabid`. It is possible to do this without the `product` part, but this would make your life a lot harder as you would have to go through a lot of trouble to still have access to `Admin` and `Dev` for example. 
If you want the shortest URL you should make a new Page, as your current `ProductPage` is a child of another page, telling from your URL:

> www.mysite.com/category/subcat/productid

You can achieve the best scenario with this code:

```
class ProductRedirectPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{
    private static $allowed_actions = [
        'Product'
    ];

    private static $url_handlers = [
        '$ID/$TabID' => 'Product'
    ];

    public function Product()
    {
        // Get your ProductPage, this should work if there is only one ProductPage
        $page = ProductPage::get()->first();

        if(! $productId = $this->request->param('ID'))
            return $this->redirect($page->Link()); // or send them somewhere else

        $tabId = $this->request->param('TabID');

        $link = $page->Link('yourAction/' . $productId . '/' . $tabId);

        return $this->redirect($link);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**
With this code, when `www.mysite.com/product/productid/tabid` is visited, it will redirect you to where your `ProductPage` is. Maybe you wish to change the `/$tabId` to `?tabId=' . $tabId`, but that is totally up to you.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful! Unfortunately I do need it shorter. As I already have a redirector set up for each product: b) www.mysite.com/productid (which goes to the full URL), in theory I could create 3 more child redirectors for each product redirector i.e www.mysite.com/productid/tabid set to redirect to c) www.mysite.com/category/subcat/productid/tabid, is there a way to code this to save me manually making each child redirector page each time...

Comment: Thank you for this, one thing I should mention is that "tabid" is not a page. "ProductPage" has no children. It contains 4 tabs which can be visited via "/?=tabid" (the ID's are: videos,photos,firmware,audio). Also the exact URL for each product page is as follows: 1. www.mysite.com/products/category/subcat/productid and to change tabs is 2. www.mysite.com/products/category/subcat/productid?=tabid, So the result I need is this url takes you to example 2: www.mysite.com/productid/tabid, apologies if this changes things!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find a good method to achieve this - I don't think there is a clean one at all. So I'll just delete my edit and stick with my earlier answer that handles www.mydomain.com/product/productID/tagID. Isn't it just easier to change the redirects? As you would only need to squeeze one word in the link.

Comment: When you say change the redirects, what exactly do you mean? I need 5 redirects per product, which was why I was hoping it could be don't in the productpage class rather than creating multiple redirectors for each product..

Comment: So basically, you just want to call a short URL, just to redirect you to the long url? Or do you want to stay at the short URL?

Comment: Just short to long, but there is 5 per page, So I don't want to have to manually create the redirectors for every product that is uploaded.

Comment: I've edited my answer, is this what you were looking for? If not, maybe you should consider opening a new question, with a slightly better explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm to summarise, you want newpage/video to open the correct on page tab, rather than being an action to render a different page?

You could do something funky with `private static $url_handlers`, to set a parameter you could query through $request->param('Thing').

Or you could set up handleAction to test whether or not $action either is one of the things in the list (and set flags for later use in eg. a template), or otherwise parent::handleAction.

This answer isn't extremely fleshed out, but should hopefully provide you some ideas on directions to investigate for your own use case.